# Module interface is in loaded NED files

Tags: omnet++

While running a omnetpp project , i got the following error for which i've searched enough on internet but was unable to find any solution.

```
Error in module (cCompoundModule) InetUnderlayNetwork2.overlayAccessRouter[0] (id=5) during network setup: Submodule tier2: 
no module type named `' found that implements module interface oversim.common.ITier (not in the loaded NED files?),

 at g:\gaurav\omnetpp-4.2.2-src-windows\omnetpp-4.2.2\samples\denacast\src\underlay\inetunderlay\OverlayAccessRouter.ned:81.
```

Here what does mean by not in the loaded NED files.I'm completely unable to understand the second error line.

The OverlayAceessRouter.ned file is following:-

```
package oversim.underlay.inetunderlay;

import inet.base.NotificationBoard;
import inet.linklayer.ethernet.EthernetInterface;
import inet.linklayer.ppp.PPPInterface;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTable;
import inet.nodes.inet.NetworkLayer;
import inet.transport.udp.UDP;
import oversim.common.BootstrapList;
import oversim.common.CryptoModule;
import oversim.common.IOverlay;
import oversim.common.ITier;
import oversim.common.NeighborCache;


//
// Access router that participates in the overlay
//
// @author Markus Mauch, Bernhard Heep
//
module OverlayAccessRouter
{
    parameters:
        @node();
        string routingFile = default("");
        string overlayType; // overlay protocol compound module to use
        string tier1Type; // tier 1 application to use
        string tier2Type; // tier 2 module to use
        string tier3Type; // tier 3 module to use
        int numTiers; // number of tiers

        @display("bgb=361,464");
    gates:
        inout pppg[]; // gates from overlay
        inout ethg[]; // placeholder for zero-size vector
        input overlayNeighborArrowIn[]; // incoming gate for visualizing overlay neighborship with connection arrows
        output overlayNeighborArrowOut[]; // incoming gate for visualizing overlay neighborship with connection arrows

    submodules:
        notificationBoard: NotificationBoard {
            parameters:
                @display("p=76,192;i=block/control");
        }
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=76,262;i=block/table");
        }
        routingTable: RoutingTable {
            parameters:
                IPForward = true;
                routerId = "auto";
                routingFile = routingFile;
                @display("p=76,340;i=block/table");
        }
        accessNet: AccessNet {
            parameters:
                @display("p=76,402;i=block/cogwheeli");
        }
        tier3: <tier3Type> like ITier {
            parameters:
                @display("p=56,64;i=block/segm");
        }
        tier2: <tier2Type> like ITier {
            parameters:
                @display("p=139,88;i=block/segm");
        }
        tier1: <tier1Type> like ITier {
            parameters:
                @display("p=218,122;i=block/segm");
        }
        overlay: <overlayType> like IOverlay {
            parameters:
                @display("p=290,184;i=block/network2");
        }
        udp: UDP {
            parameters:
                @display("p=290,262;i=block/transport");
        }
        networkLayer: NetworkLayer {
            parameters:
                proxyARP = false;
                @display("p=290,340;i=block/fork;q=queue");
            gates:
                ifIn[sizeof(pppg)+sizeof(ethg)];
                ifOut[sizeof(pppg)+sizeof(ethg)];
        }
        ppp[sizeof(pppg)]: PPPInterface {
            parameters:
                @display("p=290,414,row,90;q=txQueue;i=block/ifcard");
        }
        eth[sizeof(ethg)]: EthernetInterface {
            parameters:
                @display("p=286,268,row,110;q=queue;i=block/ifcard");
        }
        neighborCache: NeighborCache {
            parameters:
                @display("p=168,262;i=block/table");
        }
        bootstrapList: BootstrapList {
            parameters:
                @display("p=168,340;i=block/table");
        }
        cryptoModule: CryptoModule {
            parameters:
                @display("p=168,402");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        tier1.to_lowerTier --> overlay.appIn if numTiers>0;
        tier1.from_lowerTier <-- overlay.appOut if numTiers>0;
        tier1.udpOut --> udp.appIn++ if numTiers>0;
        udp.appOut++ --> tier1.udpIn if numTiers>0;

        tier2.to_lowerTier --> tier1.from_upperTier if numTiers > 1;
        tier2.from_lowerTier <-- tier1.to_upperTier if numTiers > 1;
        tier2.udpOut --> udp.appIn++ if numTiers>1;
        udp.appOut++ --> tier2.udpIn if numTiers>1;

        tier3.to_lowerTier --> tier2.from_upperTier if numTiers > 2;
        tier3.from_lowerTier <-- tier2.to_upperTier if numTiers > 2;
        tier3.udpOut --> udp.appIn++ if numTiers>2;
        udp.appOut++ --> tier3.udpIn if numTiers>2;

        overlay.udpOut --> udp.appIn++;
        overlay.udpIn <-- udp.appOut++;

        bootstrapList.udpOut --> udp.appIn++;
        bootstrapList.udpIn <-- udp.appOut++;

        udp.ipOut --> networkLayer.udpIn;
        udp.ipIn <-- networkLayer.udpOut;

        // connections to network outside
        for i=0..sizeof(pppg)-1 {
            pppg[i] <--> ppp[i].phys;
            ppp[i].netwOut --> networkLayer.ifIn[i];
            ppp[i].netwIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut[i];
        }

        for i=0..sizeof(ethg)-1 {
            ethg[i] <--> eth[i].phys;
            eth[i].netwOut --> networkLayer.ifIn[sizeof(pppg)+i];
            eth[i].netwIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut[sizeof(pppg)+i];
        }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may have omitted the `tier2Type` parameter, which is necessary for the `tier2` submodule to be added, as it seems to say that it's empty.
You will want to specify the value for `tier2Type` where it is missing in the simulation configuration.